# Finding inverse using one step subgroup test

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> $G=GL\left ( n,\mathbb{R} \right )$
>
> $H= \{ A \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})|AA^{T}=I  \}$

Is $H$ a subgroup of group $G$?

$G$ is a group so $G$ contains the identity element.

$A=I=e.$ Then, $AA^{T}=II^{T}=I$
Indeed, $I\in H$ so $H \not\equiv \varnothing $

We have the that the identity element is contained in $H$ and $H$ is non-empty.

Because $H$ is non-empty, we pick $a$ and $b$ from $H$.
Let $A=a=I$ and let $A=b=I\quad \forall a,b\in H \quad\forall A \in G$

Then,$a*b^{-1}=II^{-1}=I\ $so$\ a*b^{-1} \in H$
Closure is satisfied.

Existence of inverse is giving me a very hard time. I find myself unable to see through the wood for the forest and getting confused with what I am trying to achieve.

Here's my attempt:
Obviously, $e \in H.$ So let $a=e$.

Some help henceforth would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $H\leq G$ you should show $\forall A,B \in H \quad AB^{-1}\in H$ .

At first we know $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$
And because $A^TA=I$ then $A^T=A^{-1}$ so $AA^T=AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=A^TA$

Therefore  $(A^{-1}{A^{-1}}^T)^{-1}=A^TA=I$, Thus $A^{-1}{A^{-1}}^T=I$ .

Now $(AB^{-1})(AB^{-1})^T=AB^{-1}{B^{-1}}^TA^T=AIA^T=I$

Thus $H$is a subgroup of $G$, called [Orthogonal subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) .

Comment: Would it be better to determine first whether the one-step subgroup theorem holds first before determining if the defining property holds?